# How to use If with an afterTextChangeListener?

Tags: android, if-statement

So my Idea is to listen in an EditText for a number, exemple 1. When the user but in the EditText the number 1, I want my app to do something but I dont know How to combine afterTextChangeListener with if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // you can write any condition or logic here.

         if(editText1.getText().toString.equals("1"){
               // You can apply your logic here
         }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {
    private EditText yourEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);

        yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(yourEditText.getText().toString().equals("1")) {
                    //Rest of the code goes here
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    } 

    @Override 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    } 

    @Override 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // you can write any condition or logic here. 
        String textEntered = editText1.getText().toString();
        if(isNumeric(textEntered)){ 
            // You can apply your logic here 
        } 
    } 
}); 

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) { 
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
}
```

Comment: that was not required @ Ziem.